# ReduxForm error when changing value of a radioButton

Tags: redux-form

Im using reduxform to generate a survey which includes some radiobutton questions. The problem is that whenever I change the value of the radio button I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Must access array elements with a number, not "undefined".
    at deleteInWithPath (deleteIn.js:21)
    at deleteInWithPath (deleteIn.js:35)
    at deleteIn (deleteIn.js:61)
    at createReducer.js:233
    at reducer (createReducer.js:548)
    at createReducer.js:566
    at combination (combineReducers.js:120)
    at autoRehydrate.js:30
    at computeNextEntry (<anonymous>:2:27469)
    at recomputeStates (<anonymous>:2:27769)
```

I don't know what is causing the error so any helped to spot it would be appreciated.

This is the component that render the radio buttons.

```
export const QuestionYesNo=({question,valueQuestion,metaData})=>{
  let error=null;

  if(metaData!==undefined){
    if(metaData[question.id]!==undefined){
      if((valueQuestion(question.id)===undefined ||valueQuestion(question.id)==='') && metaData[question.id].touched===true){
        error=<h4 style={{color:'red'}}>¡Required!</h4>
      }
    }
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <div className="question">
        <div><h3>{question.ordinal+"- "+question.name}</h3></div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <Field
              name={""+question.id}
              component="input"
              type="radio"
              value="YES"
            />{' '}
            Si
          </label>
          <label>
            <Field
              name={""+question.id}
              component="input"
              type="radio"
              value="NO"
            />{' '}
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      {error}

    </div>


  );
};
```

The above component is inside another component in a loop for each question. The component that contains the above component is the one that has the reduxForm.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you create a sample on JsFiddle (or similar) that recreates this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug/limitation of redux-form. Prefix your field names with a letter or with a letter followed by a period if you want your form values to be in an array when passed to onSubmit.

So rather than

`name={""+question.id}`

do

`name={"question"+question.id}` // results in {question0: "foo", question1: "bar"}

or (if your ids are monotonically increasing integers starting from zero):

`name={"questions."+question.id}` // results in array {questions: ["foo", "bar"]}

More info: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3753#issuecomment-406435226